# Getter method not working in enhanced loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, getter

I'm making an enhanced for loop to sort through part objects in my part array list. But when the enhanced for loop gets to the if statement it doesn't do anything(with exception to `Damper`) and there are no errors so i don't know why it's not working. `thelist` is the name of my array list holding objects.

```
    for(int z=0; z<20; z++){
        displayMenu();
            int selection = sc.nextInt();
            if(selection == 0){
                System.out.println("You have exited the system");
            } else if(selection == 1){  
                System.out.println("Choose stock name to replenish");
                for(Part y: thelist){
                    String nS = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print(nS);
                    if(nS.equals(y.getName())){
                        System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
                        int qty = sc.nextInt();
                        y.replenish(qty);
                        System.out.println("Complete");
                    }
                }
            } else if
```

My objects

```
    Part part0 = new Part("p100", "Spring", 43, 120);
    Part part1 = new Part("p101", "Damper", 72, 150);
    Part part2 = new Part("p102", "Lower CA", 38, 80);
    Part part3 = new Part("p103", "Upper CA", 26, 70);
```

And just to show that up to
['String nS'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIl15.png) is working

Also, it works for Damper only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You need to add

```
sc.nextLine();
```

After

```
int qty = sc.nextInt();
```

And add the same after

```
int selection = sc.nextInt();
```

To consume the newline character.

Secondly, if you are trying to search nS, why do you place it inside the for loop? Place it outside the for loop and then search.

```
    String nS = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print(nS);

    for (Part y : thelist) {
        if (nS.equals(y.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
            int qty = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            y.replenish(qty);
            System.out.println("Complete");
        }
    }
```

Comment: No because it's not even getting to there. It never prints "Please enter replenish quantity". Except for Damper. And when i put Damper in it works fine

Comment: I think he meant before !

Comment: doing this just skips everything and it loops back to displayMenu()

Comment: @dansey I updated it. You need to add sc.nextLine() everytime you call sc.nextInt();

Comment: @dansey Can you show a runnable code with examples?

Comment: why is that necessary?

Comment: @dansey sorry, our comments clashed.

Comment: @BOND lol no why do i have to add sc.nextLine(); after every sc.nextInt()?

Comment: @dansey because sc.nextInt() doesn't consume the new line character so you need to clear it yourself by sc.nextLine() so that the next time you call sc.nextLine(), the program waits for user input as there is nothing in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using nextInt then nextLine and the again nextInt. The new line char messes you up.

```
for(int z=0; z<20; z++){
    displayMenu();
        int selection = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        if(selection == 0){
            System.out.println("You have exited the system");
        } else if(selection == 1){  
            System.out.println("Choose stock name to replenish");
            for(Part y: thelist){
                String nS = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print(nS);
                if(nS.equals(y.getName())){
                    System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                    y.replenish(qty);
                    System.out.println("Complete");
                }
            }
        } else if
```